# Transparent URL rewrite on Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

On my Nginx server I have a url 1

http://www.example.com/component/abc/categories

and I want it to rewrite the request to url 2

http://www.example.com/abc/categories

without url 1 being changed in the address bar.

I have tried several examples that I've found in the config file, but no results. I appreciate your help.

[update] here is another attempt. I think alias would be the right choice, if I get the expressions right. This should work, but it redirects to the homepage. What am I doing wrong?

`location ~ ^/component/(.*)$ {
    alias /var/www/example.com/www/abc/$1;
}`

Comment: And what you have tried?

Comment: I've tried:

location /component/ {
    rewrite ^/component/(.*)$ $scheme://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
} but this one redirects the url and changes the one in the address bar too.

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Edit the post

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I couldn't post code in comments. I've updated the question.

Comment: try this `location /component/ { alias /; }`. alias is a replacement for location, not a local path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do it simplest way?

```
location /component/ {
  rewrite ^/component(.*) $1 last;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know that is the right answer, although for some reason it isn't working on my server as if it never parses the /component/ block to execute that line.

Comment: I'm 99% sure you have regexp location (like *.php). You could use `location ^~ /component/ { ... }` to prevent regexp locations for `/component/`